# Is Peter Sripol’s Mk4 ultralight design safe and/or practical?

Tags: ultralight, aircraft-structures, plane-construction

I recently rewatched Peter Sripol’s Mk4 ultralight video

Obviously, the aircraft flew, but I have several questions as a result.

First and foremost, is a vinyl-covered foam wing with an aluminum spar really safe? If so, is this a practical construction method offering advantages over typical ultralight wing construction techniques?

Secondly, does anyone know what type of foam was used? Would a carbon fiber spar have been better than an aluminum spar? And finally, is there any particular reason that the wings’ internal structure was arranged the way it was?

Comment: I don't have a definitive source for this, but I seem to remember from his videos that he uses insulation foam [like this](https://www.amazon.com.au/Pink-Insulation-Foam-Thick/dp/B074VPZ8SS) for building most of his planes.

Comment: That’s what I’ve been thinking as well, just wanted someone to back me up on it. Thanks!

Comment: Define “safe”  Which hazards do you have in mind?

Comment: As such, I consider this question to be too broad and opinion based. Safety and praecticality should be assessed separately, and quite frankly they are not that easy to define.

Comment: @Jim I’m mostly concerned about the strength of the foam wing- clearly it survived the sandbag test and can fly, but it just doesn’t seem right to me.

Answer (score 2):

Peter uses that white polystyrene foam, the stuff used for molded packaging that produces the little white peas when it breaks down, which is pretty weak stuff and I would prefer to use the closed cell polystyrene (Styrofoam SM or similar) that the Rutan designs used, or if there was any chance of fuel or solvents getting near it, polyurethane foam (Quickie 2 builders went with polyurethane for the front wing after fuel leaks that migrated through the fiberglass dissolved the polystyrene in the wing and caused a couple of spar failures).

The stick on vinyl covering probably works fine as long as you aren't taking any credit for it strength wise, and you would need to do your own long term environmental testing to see how it and the adhesive holds up to UV.

The biggest problem with the Mk4 is the 2 axis control.  Roll control by slithering and sliding around, depending on dihedral angle to generate roll rates, is really suboptimal.  It needs more span, most of the dihedral taken out, and ailerons.

The electric power is great, but you are still stuck with about a third of the range of gas engine, pound for pound of all up weight.  Electric power would be more suitable for an ultralight with some soaring capability, unless all you ever expect to do is fly for an hour or 90 minutes locally and land.  A project I'm interested in doing is a [Kolb Ultra Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolb_Ultrastar) (you can buy scratch plans for it) powered with two 15hp RC motors.

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect to see a significantly larger rudder on a plane that is entirely dependent on slip-roll coupling for roll control authority.  In fact that would allow a slightly more modest dihedral angle, making the plane somewhat less vulnerable to crosswind gusts, though naturally an aircraft with two-axis controls (no ailerons) and generous dihedral will always be rather vulnerable to crosswind gusts.  Search the web for photos of early (no-aileron) models of the "Super Floater" ultralight sailplanes for examples of a configuration that might be closer to optimal for an aircraft without ailerons.

None of which means the MK4 would actually be unsafe *if flown in appropriate conditions*. Just that the window of "appropriate conditions" is quite small.

Answer (score 1):

> is MK4 ultralight design safe and/or practical?

They did do the sand bag test to 3 G on the wing and corrected the flutter issue on the rear horizontal stabilizer, but a complete structural strength and durability analysis is beyond what was provided in the video. Adding extra wing$^1$ and upgrading the prop definitely seemed to help.

This ultralight was made by scaling up a radio controlled model, which is a good indication that the *design* or planform will be practical, if not strongly Piper Cub - like.

Key to evaluating "dihedral content" is **vertical center of gravity**, which on this plane (with its 200 lb wing) is around the pilots head.  There is adequate area *below the CG* to compensate for the wing dihedral, though 1/3 to 1/2 less might be better.  Mounting the engine(s) higher up (on the wing) would be another way.  Anhedralling the tail, as seen on the [Lazair](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraflight_Lazair) is also possible, but side paneling the fuselage or lowering the vertical stabilizer a bit is much easier.

Tubular aluminum may be stiffer than carbon fibre for the wing spar, but again one may reference a tried and true full scale building technique rather than trying to scale a r/c model.

Overall, with refinements, the MK4 shows promise as a fun-to-fly electric ultralight.

$^1$ adding more wing span will increase "dihedral effect"